# Long Browsing Time for Data Searching

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have created an application to allow users browse for data from my database. The code works, but the only problem is it took a lot of time to load the searching result. This was due to there were about 1 million rows of data inside every table of my Access database. It also took some time for the Window Form to load... Does anyone know how can I shorten the time for the data searching?

```
Private Sub MovieBrowser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=1MDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle AS MovieTitle, m.startYear AS StartYear, m.runtimeMinutes AS Runtime, m.genres AS Genre, d.primaryName AS Director, c.writers AS Writer, r.averageRating AS Rating, d.primaryProfession AS Profession, ('www.imdb.com/title/' + m.tconst) AS URL From Movie m, Director d, Crew c, Rating r WHERE m.tconst=c.tconst AND d.nconst = c.directors AND r.tconst=m.tconst"

        conn.Open()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet("Movies1")
        'fills the dataset with data
        da.Fill(ds, "Movies1")
        'assign the datasource to the DataGridView
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Movies1")
        conn.Close()

        txtSrchbar.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't store/try to reuse the Connection. Create a new one when needed and dispose of it in-place. Possibly enclosing its declaratioin in a `Using` block. DataAdapter and Command (if present) included.

Comment: It looks likethe bottleneck in your application might be the amount of data. Fetching one million sets of data and putting them into a data grid does take some time. You could probably speed up the fetching a little bit by optimizing your database (by using the right indexes), but I'm afraid most of the time will be taken from the UI to render the data. Maybe you can change your code to only show search results when there are less than (let's say) a 1000 hits. Otherwise you could show something like "Too many search results."

Comment: You are aware of the 2GB limit? Move to Sql-Server (Express Edition is free) or MySQL, MariaDB or Postgre. The  query-time of a database is strong related to proper indexing and amount of data. All fields in Where-Clause are indexed? You should search inside the SQL-Query with a Where-Clause instaed first fetch all data and then search them.

Comment: And by the way as I notice your last questions here, did you ever tried`MS-Access`as Front-End? That is much easier to use with databases than .Net is (a form with bound-fields is created in less time, because almost everything you need is availible from scratch.). I don't like MS-Access as backend-db (try to backup data while db is in use, no EXPLAIN, no Stored Procedures, poor multi-user performance, etc), but no Front-End is more RAD!

Comment: Add indexes, avoid like query filters, use queries decomposition. Don't load all data to data grids, but only top 1000 maybe.

Answer (score 0):

It making no sense to pull the whole table.

A bank machines does not load every account and THEN let you search.

A web browser does not load the WHOLE internet and THEN let you search.

1 million rows is not a lot of data for Access.

Simple put some text boxes or some such at the top of your form.

Let the user type in an invoice number, or some other criteria and THEN load the grid.

You don’t want to use the grid for searching, but only for display of the data.

So, say we are searching for movies in a given year.

You might have a text box called part number at the top. The  usr types in the  part number, or say the movie year, then your sql becomes:

```
strSQL = "your sql”

strSQL = strSQL & " AND MovieYear = " & me.txtMyear

' code to fill the grid.
```

Now the grid will ONLY load movies from that year. You can add additional search boxes.

Make sure a index exists for any column that you search on.

Even with 1 million rows, pulling and restricting the results you send into the grid should occur VERY fast. The access data engine is VERY fast for such operations.